# Can a webpart (or sharepoint automatically) track user accessed docs/lists?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Is it possible to track user actions in SharePoint from a Web Part? Or even better...does SharePoint 2010 automatically tracks users actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can enable Auditing and read the Audit log programatically :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466223(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks, let me see how it works and I'll let you know if that's what I'm looking for.